# Why is next/previous in-order traversal node always an external node?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

In a binary search tree, if you take any internal (non-leaf) node, why is the next (or previous) in-order traversal node of that node is always an external (leaf) node?

Comment: Define internal/external node? Is this like parent/child branch/leaf?

Comment: external is just leaf, internal is not

Comment: You contradict yourself in definition of external node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't necessarily true.  Try this tree:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
```

Here, the inorder successor of 2 is 3, which is an internal node, and its inorder predecessor is 1, which is also an internal node.

Hope this helps!